# PyQt4 - How to Return and Saving the path of choosen directory

Tags: python, directory, path, pyqt4

I am trying to create a pop-up wizard that would have the user select a Directory path, save that path into a variable, and return that path to be used in another script.

I am relatively new to coding in Python, and I'm just playing around. I tried Tkinter, but did not like the look/feel of the library. While PyQt was overall nicer to work with. I've tried to set up the buttons a few different ways with little success. I've tried to use 'self' and the 'self.variable' as shown through YouTube videos but I'm unfamiliar with how this is helpful and used.

When there is a path selected, it will print the output, but it does not seem to be returning the path to use, and if it is, I am unaware of how it is doing so and how to use it in other script.

As a side note: I put a '2' inside of QtGui.QBoxLayout() because code would not work without it.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui



class Window(QtGui.QWizard):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(550, 350, 700, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Output Directory")

        path = self.home_menu()
        print("This path: {}".format(path))

        return path

    def home_menu(self):   
        out_dir = QtGui.QPushButton("Output Directory", self)
        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Confirm", self)
        path = self.file_open

        out_path = out_dir.clicked.connect(path)
        print('Out_path: {}\nVariable Type: {}'.format(out_path, type(out_path)))

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.using_path) #does nothing

        btn1.resize(112, 35)
        btn1.move(556, 535)

        out_dir.resize(625,175)
        out_dir.move(30,130)


        layout = QtGui.QBoxLayout(2) #Don't know why I put '2' but code does not work without it.
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(out_dir)
        self.show()

        return out_path

    #Sets the Style of the Window   
    def style_choice(self, text):
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create(text))


    def file_open(self):
        name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        #self, "Choose Directory", "")
        print('path opened: {}'.format(name)) #Prints names
        return name



    def close_app(self):
        choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Are you sure?',
                                            'Do you really want to exit the program?',
                                            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            print('Exiting Program Now!')
            sys.exit()
        else:
            pass


    def using_path():
        try:
            directory = 0
            print("Returned path is: {}".format(directory))
            return 
        except:
            print('... progress bar failed')




def mainWindow():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainWindow()
```

I cannot get the paths to output and the confirm button does not work or do anything.

I appreciate any help that can be give. Thank you!

Comment: `__init__` can't return value - it is executed when you create instance but code returns class's instance not value from `__init__`

Comment: assing path to variable in class - ie `self.path` and get it after `app.exec()` as `GUI.path`. But remove `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

Assign path to `self.path` and later get `GUI.path` after `app.exec_()` but you have to skip `sys.exit()`

```
import sys
import os
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWizard):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.path = '' # default value at start (useful if you don't select new directory)

        #layout = QtGui.QBoxLayout(QtGui.QBoxLayout.TopToBottom) 
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        btn_out_dir = QtGui.QPushButton("Output Directory", self)
        btn_out_dir.clicked.connect(self.path_select)
        layout.addWidget(btn_out_dir)

        btn_confirm = QtGui.QPushButton("Confirm", self)
        btn_confirm.clicked.connect(self.close)
        layout.addWidget(btn_confirm)

    def path_select(self):
        self.path = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
        if self.path:
            print('[inside] path:', self.path)
        else:
            print('[inside] path: - not selected -')


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

GUI = Window()
GUI.show()

status_code = app.exec_()

print('[outside] path:', GUI.path)

#sys.exit(status_code)
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment, and answer. It work, but it does not allow me to send this variable to another script. How would I do this?

Comment: this problem has nothing to do with GUI/Qt. Normally we `import` code from other Python's file and use it in current program - without exiting - so all code has access to current variables. If you want to run it in different way then you may have to save it in file and other script will have to read it from file. Or you run script with arguments `"python script.py some_path"` and script get it in `sys.argv[1]`